# Application supporting scripting in PDF forms on mobile devices

Tags: android, pdf, ios, pdf-viewer, forms

Is there any PDF reader allowing to fill out PDF forms (preferably XFA but Acroforms could be acceptable) and able to execute basic scripting (to make validations, filter items in a dropdown, disable fields or make them mandatory … following the value entered somewhere else)?

It should be available on iOS and Android at least. (I could be a different application per system and it doesn't need to be free … while it is preferable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XFA, you can forget anything on mobile devices; here, you'd have to follow the original intention of XFA, namely to provide a description which allows a server to properly render the form after having sniffed the viewer's capability.

For Acroforms, the leader of the pack is PDFExpert by Readdle for iOS, and qPDF Notes for Android (however, it is weaker than PDFExpert (supporting fewer objects, methods and properties, and we discovered some fundamental bugs which prevented forms from working properly, and required a reprogramming of the forms).

Answer (score 1):

For Acroforms, Adobe's Acrobat Reader for iOS/Android supports some of the scripts, I can't find any documentation on what is and isn't supported though (I have done very limited testing of my own).

[PDF Expert from Readdle](https://readdle.com/products/pdfexpert5) (iOS only) is recommended in [other forums](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/javacscript-does-not-work-on-ipad-q67903.aspx) when this question comes up.

Comment: With all due respect, but Adobe Reader for iOS/Android is useless when it comes to smart forms. Have a look at the documentation, and you will be horrified of the number of objects, methods and properties supported…